# hide perl Expect output

Tags: perl, stdout, expect

I've got a perl script that automatically logs me via `ssh` by spawning ssh with `Expect.pm`.

It actually works pretty well and here is my ouput:

```
    $ ngh bestServerEver
    GPG Pass : 
    root@**********'s password: 
    Linux **** 2.6.32-042stab059.7 #1 SMP Tue Jul 24 19:12:01 MSK 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
    motd!!!!!!!!!!
    Last login: Mon Feb  4 22:18:10 2013 from *******************
    bash
    [root@******:~]$ bash
    [root@******:~]$
```

I'm trying to suppress this output to get to the server shell directly after typing my command. Like that:

```
$ngh BestServerEver
root@server#
```

I've tried that answer:
[How can I suppress STDOUT temporarily in a Perl program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376607/how-can-i-suppress-stdout-temporarily-in-a-perl-program)

I've also tried:

```
    local (*OUT, *ERR);
    open OUT, ">&STDOUT";
    open ERR, ">&STDERR";
    close STDOUT;
    close STDERR;
    print "don't print";
    open STDOUT, ">&OUT";
    open STDERR, ">&ERR";
```

Both are okay when it's about standard STDOUT but Expect seems to be a different kind of handle or whatever.

I've also tried setting:

```
$exp->stty("-echo");
```

But it did not hide anything

Finally, here is my code http://pastebin.com/pSL3AwBW if you have some tips to give me on how to hide that junk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Expect.pm) tell you to use

```
$exp->log_stdout(0);
```

Tested:

```
$ perl -MExpect -E'
   my $e = Expect->spawn("cat");
   $e->log_stdout($ARGV[0]);
   $e->send("abc\n"); $e->expect(undef, "abc");
   $e->send("def\n"); $e->expect(undef, "def");
   say "done."
' 1
abc
def
done.

$ perl -MExpect -E'
   my $e = Expect->spawn("cat");
   $e->log_stdout($ARGV[0]);
   $e->send("abc\n"); $e->expect(undef, "abc");
   $e->send("def\n"); $e->expect(undef, "def");
   say "done."
' 0
done.
```

Comment: Well that helps a lot! thank you! But would I still get the output from the commands i send : when i send $exp->send("bash"); it ouputs :  
    
    bash (then)
    [root@server:~]$ bash (then)
    [root@server:~]$

Comment: i might have done something wrong in my script since it actually does print it : with debug to 3, --->  Attempting interconnection ---> interconnect: read 51 byte(s) from spawn id(3). ---> Printed '\033[01;32m[root@server\033[00m:\033[01;34m~]\033[00m$ bash\r\n' to handle id(5) from spawn id(3). ---> [root@server:~]$ bash <--- But thanks anyway i'll try to figure it out ;)